# responsive design not working when testing in browser when resizing

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am making a very simple website countdown website with one image and 2 lines of text(including the countdown). I want to make it responsible to the device width. When someone  sees this website on mobile or tablet I want the fonts to be smaller. I have used media query. When I want to test it in my PC browser (by resizing the browser window) It is not working. Can anyone tell me what could be wrong?

HTML:

```
 <head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=width, initial-scale=1.0;">
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
 <title>Countdown</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/main.css" />
 <script type='text/javascript'src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
     // countdown script
 </script>
 </head>

 <body>
 <div id="content">

     <div id="zasuvka"></div>     //here is my image
     <p id="ele">TITLE</p>       // here is the title

     <div id="odpocet" >
     <div id="prichadza">Remains: </div> <div id="countdown"></div>   //here is shown the countdown
     </div>

     <div id="show" style="display:none">     // div that will show after the countdown
     <a href="#" target="_blank">LINK</a>
     </div>

 </div>
 </body>
```

CSS:

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

  #prichadza {
 font-size:24px;
 float:left;
 text-align:center;
 font-family:"sans";
 color:#ffffff;
 padding-top:10px;
 }

 #countdown{
 padding-left:10px;
 font-size:24px;
 font-family:"sans";
 color:#a54d14;
 }
 }

 body{
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#e4cf8e, #fdf7e5); /* For Safari */
 background: -o-linear-gradient(#e4cf8e, #fdf7e5); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(#e4cf8e, #fdf7e5); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
 background: linear-gradient(#e4cf8e, #fdf7e5); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
 }

 @font-face
 {
 font-family: sans;
 src: url(../fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf);
 }


 #content{
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
 }

 #zasuvka {
 width:318px;
 height:303px;
 background:url('../img/zasuvka.png')no-repeat;
 margin:auto;
 margin-top:120px;
 }

 #countdown{
 padding-left:10px;
 font-size:44px;
 float:left;
 font-family:"sans";
 color:#a54d14;
 }

 #ele {
 font-family:"sans";
 font-size: 48px;
 color:#a54d14;
 margin:0px;
 padding-top:30px;
 }

 #prichadza {
 font-size:34px;
 float:left;
 text-align:center;
 font-family:"sans";
 color:#a54d14;
 padding-top:10px;
 }

 #odpocet {
 width:600px;
 padding-left:95px;
 margin:auto;
 }

 #show a {
 font-size:44px;
 text-align:center;
 font-family:"sans";
 color:#a54d14;
 }
```

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: You have used media query for div with ID prichadza, but it is not in your HTML. If you're populating that with js, mark font-size and other style attributes important.

Comment: my fault, I made a mistake when copying code. I have that div in my html. I edited my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move "@media screen and (max-width: 480px)" at the end of the css document!
So it would look like:

```
 body{
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#e4cf8e, #fdf7e5); /* For Safari */
 background: -o-linear-gradient(#e4cf8e, #fdf7e5); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(#e4cf8e, #fdf7e5); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
 background: linear-gradient(#e4cf8e, #fdf7e5); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
 }

 @font-face
 {
 font-family: sans;
 src: url(../fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf);
 }


 #content{
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
 }

 #zasuvka {
 width:318px;
 height:303px;
 background:url('../img/zasuvka.png')no-repeat;
 margin:auto;
 margin-top:120px;
 }

 #countdown{
 padding-left:10px;
 font-size:44px;
 float:left;
 font-family:"sans";
 color:#a54d14;
 }

 #ele {
 font-family:"sans";
 font-size: 48px;
 color:#a54d14;
 margin:0px;
 padding-top:30px;
 }

 #prichadza {
 font-size:34px;
 float:left;
 text-align:center;
 font-family:"sans";
 color:#a54d14;
 padding-top:10px;
 }

 #odpocet {
 width:600px;
 padding-left:95px;
 margin:auto;
 }

 #show a {
 font-size:44px;
 text-align:center;
 font-family:"sans";
 color:#a54d14;
 }

 @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
      #prichadza {
     font-size:24px;
     float:left;
     text-align:center;
     font-family:"sans";
     color:#green;
     padding-top:10px;
     }

     #countdown{
     padding-left:10px;
     font-size:24px;
     font-family:"sans";
     color:#a54d14;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

i see that in your css you have a media query for screen less or equal to 480px
...inside it you define #prichadza and #countdown ....but then you define these two again - this time "outside" of the media query with different values to the same properties. It will not work like that - you need to add `!important` in your rules inside media query or you need to specify another media query `screen and (min-width:481px)` and define here the rules for screen bigger than 480 instead of that rules you placed "outside".

for first solution you just need something like this.:

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #prichadza {
         font-size:24px !important;
    }
  }
```

...and your #prichadza font-size will do change now.